# GDS doesn't show all rows / sum all values when I have 2 same rows of blending data

Tags: looker-studio

GDS doesn't show all rows / sum all values when I have 2 same rows of blending data.

I am doing a report that shows data filtered by email.
It took me 2 days but hopeless to find the root cause

Please see the screenshot for what I mean
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJJAn.png

Here's the GDS file.
https://datastudio.google.com/s/kPkRpwDTqbc

Comment: Is the `Record Count` 1 or 2 if it is added to the table? Dove is mapped to another email and therefore not shown? How you blend the data? Are the metric of that table in dimension or metrics and how aggregated?

Comment: I have shared all of of the files. Could you please take a look and do some test? Thank you so much. It drives me crazy to find out the reason. https://datastudio.google.com/s/kPkRpwDTqbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values which should be summed up, need to be in the metrics. Then following result is archived:

[image]

Again your raw data:

| Date Sales | Rep Bill ID | Qty | Price | Total | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/08/2021 | Dove | 12345 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/08/2021 | Jone | 12346 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/08/2021 | Jone | 12346 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

and

| Staff | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Dove | dove@gmail.com |
| Jone | dotuanviet1981@gmail.com |

For joing, these values have to be in metrics, marked yellow. You put them in dimension - marked red - and therefore these counted once vor duplicated data.
[image]